# AngularJS - Routing to empty route ("/") doesn't work in IE7

Tags: angularjs, routes, internet-explorer-7

I have an AngularJS app that has all of the usual IE workaround stuff:

```
<html id="ng-app" class="ng-app:clientsite" ng-app="clientsite" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
    <head>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
          <script>
            document.createElement('ng-include');
            document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
            document.createElement('ng-view');
            document.createElement('ng:include');
            document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
            document.createElement('ng:view');
          </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
          <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

The site works and I can get to any route, except IE7 isn't picking up the empty route, "/":

```
$routeProvider
.when("/",
{
    templateUrl: "/htm/home.htm"
})
```

It's routing to my otherwise route:

```
.otherwise(
{
    templateUrl: "/htm/notfound.htm"
});
```

If I add /#/ at the end of my route, it works, but our customers aren't going to accept that (people need to be able to go to www.theirsite.com directly, we can't require www.theirsite.com/#/).

Behind the scenes I have an ASP.Net MVC server that just routes everything back to my index file (which works across the board, except this one route in IE7).

How can I get the empty route working properly in IE7?

Comment: Are you using HTML5Mode or Hashbang mode? From top of my mind, in the worst case you can use onroutechange at rootscope to do some route manipulation.

Comment: I'm using hashbang mode. What would that look like? I'm okay with an IE7 band-aid.

Comment: Have a look at the $route service events.  http://goo.gl/oCrlB . In your case you should have this events monitored on the $rootScope. You can change your route using $location. Sorry but I can not provide you any proof of concept because I am at work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this is how I worked around it:

```
.otherwise({
    templateUrl: '/app/error.html',
    resolve: {
        // Here we ensure that our route has the document fragment (#), or more specifically that it has #/ at a minimum.
        // If accessing the base URL without a trailing '/' in IE7 it will execute the otherwise route instead of the signin
        // page, so this check will ensure that '#/' exists and if not redirect accordingly which fixes the URL.
        redirectCheck: ['$location', function ($location) {
            var absoluteLocation = $location.absUrl();

            if (absoluteLocation.indexOf('#/') === -1) {
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }]
    }
});
```